# Swift enum with a custom constructor

Tags: swift, enums, init

I have a simple enum of type string:

```
enum MyEnum: String {
    case hello = "hello"
    case world = "world"
}
```

And I want to write a case-insensitive constructor.
I tried this (with or without extension):

```
init?(string: String) {
    return self.init(rawValue: string.lowercased())
}
```

but I get an error saying:

```
'nil' is the only value permitted in an initializer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to `return` anything. You just call initializer:

```
enum MyEnum: String {
    case hello = "hello"
    case world = "world"

    init?(caseInsensitive string: String) {
        self.init(rawValue: string.lowercased())
    }
}

print(MyEnum(caseInsensitive: "HELLO") as Any) // => Optional(Untitled.MyEnum.hello)
print(MyEnum(caseInsensitive: "Goodbye") as Any) // => nil
```